# How to I search Baidu's cache and Yandex's cache with a website URL?

Tags: caching, web, yandex, baidu

I am writing a program in C# that searches a cached specific website from the caches of Google, Yandex, Baidu and Wayback.

When I am searching Google's cache I am using the URL below with www.google.com as the cached website
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.google.com

How do I search for a cached website from Baidu's cache and Yandex's cache? I need a similar method like the one I used from Google's cache above but I can't find one for Baidu and Yandex.

Are there any other caches where I can search for a website using a method similar to the method I used for Google's cache above?